# RANSAC camera-calibration implementation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, outliers, ransac

I looked into several libraries like OpenCV etc, but could not find any implementation of camera calibration in RANSAC way. I mean, I want to do calibration providing point correspondences (P, p) (ie. 3D -> 2D) which can contain outliers and finally find both the inrinsic and extrinsic matrix from the inliers.
Before I go on and implement my own using some libraries like scikit (I did not find a good general RANSAC implementation in C++ as well), I wanted to know if something like that is readily available.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at OpenCV's [calibrateCamera](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibratecamera)? If you are unsure about the quality of your point correspondences, I think it would be very easy to write your own RANSAC-based calibration based on this, as the function conveniently returns the reprojection error.

Comment: Thats what I am doing it now; was looking for something already implemented. Reprojection error returned by calibrateCamera is not much usefull as one needs to get the reprojection error of new points using the existing camera matrix - and for that there is an extra call to solvePnP to get the extrinsics of the new points and then projectPoints to get the reprojection error manually. Don't think it can be done any simpler than that.

Answer (score 0):

First question to ask is: why do you want to do this?

The reason you won't find a shrink-wrapped implementation of a RANSAC loop around a whole camera calibration package is that, on the surface, it sounds like a bad idea.

Camera calibration use cases normally are (or should be) highly repeatable, low-noise affairs, with outlier-fractions small enough to be dealt with a robustifier in the bundle adjustment. If your use case is the opposite of all that, it brings into question the entire approach.

It'd help if you described your use case with more detail.

Comment: It's useful if you need to calibrate the camera from the image rather than in advance - eg. if you don't own the camera.

Comment: But you do have images of a proper calibration rig? And you can guarantee that the camera parameters do not change, either across the calibration images (so you can calibrate), nor on actual scene images? Are you perhaps confusing "camera calibration" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning)  with "camera auto-calibration" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_auto-calibration)

Comment: If you have a-priori access to the camera to take calibration images (and they don't change with zoom or focus) yes. But if you were creating a service where people could upload individual pictures taken around an object with their own camera and you created a model from point correspondances then you would need to solve for the camera matrix from the images.

Comment: @FrancescoCallari, I want to do this because I want to do calibration from noisy data - a data which guarantees that there will be a high number of accurate correspondences - giving a scope of performing calibration of the camera. Why is it a bad Idea?

Comment: Not a bad idea in general, but rather pointless. "Camera calibration" normally involves two phases: (1) an initial estimation of the camera parameters which uses linear methods, and (2) a refinement phase through (optionally robustified) bundle adjustment. If you expect a significant fraction of  outliers in your calibration imagery, then phase (1) is where it makes sense to talk about RANSAC or similar methods (e.g. MLESAC) - and even there, only if you expect large (>= 50% ) fractions of outliers, otherwise methods like least-median squares tend to be more efficient and easier to use.

Comment: And, as I was suggesting before, if you are calibrating in situations where youdo expect large fractions of outlier, perhaps it make more sense to rethink the image capture procedure and make it more predictable and repeatable.